# Preventing a fixed element from moving when mobile browser UI retracts or expands

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm facing a challenge with a fixed element in a mobile web page. I need it to remain static regardless of changes in the mobile browser's UI size.

**Issue:**

The element is styled with `position: fixed` and `height: 100lvh`.

On mobile, when the browser UI (like the address bar) hides or shows, this element shifts its position upwards, which I want to avoid.

The fixed element should stay immovable even when the mobile browser UI retracts or expands.

Here is an image of the behaviour I want:
[image]

In the image, notice how the fixed element adjusts its position with the UI change. How can I keep this element stationary during such UI changes?

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You have no control over the browser just the window it gives you unfortunately. You can only place relative to that window

Comment: make your page go full screen so the address bar is always hidden

Comment: This is super tricky to pull off and result might not be worth it. You can detect the window resize and monitor its height compare to initial load to display your nav accordingly, but it will not work consistently accross different browsers/device rotation.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So it sounds like this isn't possible with CSS, and the only way is the measure the viewport height and calculate offsets accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

If the element's style has position fixed,just set bottom instead of top ,and Exact number with px instead of vh, it will always fix postion to bottom when the top distance changing,I added a demo below you can test it

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell1">
        Cell 1
      </td>
      <td id="cell2">
        Cell 2
      </td>
      <td id="cell31">
        Cell 3
      </td>
      <td id="cell4">
        Cell 4
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell5">
        Cell 5
      </td>
      <td id="cell6">
        Cell 6
      </td>
      <td id="cell7">
        Cell 7
      </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
  document.querySelector('table').style.bottom = document.documentElement.clientHeight + 'px'
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This example still pushes the table up to the top of the screen when the browser UI shrinks